# CompizConfig doesn't work with ubuntu 18.04

Tags: compiz, 18.04

I installed CompizConfig properly with my newly installed Ubuntu 18.04 but it doesn't work. How can I fix this bug?

Comment: Does installing `ubuntu-unity-desktop` and logging with `unity` selected (the option icon) fix it?